# What does the application layer in IBM watson architecture mean?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson, watson-dialog

I created android chatbot where my android app is the Interface directly communicating with the conversation workspace. There is no other application running in between my android app and conversation workspace. In [IBM watson architecture](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/tutorials/watson_conversation_support/) there is the application layer in between the Interface and the conversation service. What exactly is the application layer and what is the use of this layer as my android app can directly communicate with the conversation workspace?

Comment: Is this the same app layer as in this diagram? https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/index.html#about Do you only want to chat or access data and other services? How many users? What type of security?

Comment: Yes this is the same app layer. Right now I want to use only the conversation service. I will chat with the bot and after the conversation with bot is finished, I will get all the context variables from the chat. Now I will send these variables to my webservice to get the results from my database. 
I doubt whether there is any use of Application layer here.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you describe, your Android app is the application layer. It is driving the conversation, is processing the context variables and accessing other web services.

Introducing an application server to handle the calls to Conversation and other services could help improve security and scalability. You have one endpoint the Android apps connect to. There, identity and access management (IAM) could be handled. The Android app would be less suspicious because it only connects to one server / services, not to many. This is the reason why most apps are utilizing a backend server, i.e., the application server.